# In Java can I uncompress tar.gz file across file systems without using temp space on destination fs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tar, gzip

I have a virtual linux machine (using AWS) with 7GB space on / fs and 4GB on /dev/shm. I have a compressed .tar.gz file (consisting of a number of files i a folder) of size 3.3GB, when uncompressed it would be 5GB. This machine is used as an ElasticBeanstalk deployment of a Java application, I cant change the disk size or run linux commands.

So what I am doing in Java in the init() method of my servlet is:

Get the compressed file from Amazon S3 and put into /dev/shm
Uncompress file into /usr/share/tomcat7 (on root fs)

Trouble is the code that uncompresses seems to copy the compressed file from /dev/shm to /usr/share/tomcat7 as it is uncompressed which causes it to fail because I dont have space on / for both uncompressed and compressed at the same time.

Why is is doing this, can I stop it doing this - here is the code extract (a wrapper round apache compress library)

```
import org.rauschig.jarchivelib.Archiver;
import org.rauschig.jarchivelib.ArchiverFactory;
.........
File indexDirFile = new File(indexDirParent).getAbsoluteFile();
indexDirFile.mkdirs();
Archiver archiver = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver(largeFile);
archiver.extract(largeFile, indexDirFile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI:Just realized that in a tar.gz file the files are tarred and then then tar file is gzipped so when uncompressing the interim step of the unzipping to a tar is difficult to avoid. However if I **manually gzip each file and then tar** as follows:

```
cd foldertozip
gzip *
cd ..
tar -cvf foldertozip.tar folderzip
```

the size of foldertozip.tar is exactly the same as the original foldertozip.tar.gz but the interim step is not required.

Then later on I can:

- Copy foldertozip.tar to 4GB fs
- Untar foldertozip.tar to 6GB fs
- for each file in foldertozip
    Decompress each .gz

So the only additional temporary space we use on 6GB fs is what is required as decompress each gz file.

I've tested this out and it worked for me.